# How to do lazy loading on Bootstrap-table when choosing the 'All' option in pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to render over 1000 rows to the page with bootstrapTable pageList option 'All'. The performance works fine when I'm choosing 10, 25, 50 and 100, but choosing the 'All' option would cause the page laggy and slow. How can I do lazy loading when scrolling down the page or other methods that can improve the performance?

```
$('#table-users').bootstrapTable({
   pagination: true,
   pageList: [10, 25, 50, 100, 'All']
 )}
```

The code above is the bootstrap plugin. I am thinking of using jQuery to detect when the scrolling down the page then keeps loading the data, but I cannot find the solution for to do (for example load 100 rows first, and the page scrolls down to the 100th row then load the next 100 rows.) this kind of magic when clicking the option 'All' in pagination.

in the bootstrap table, I try to test it on just one column.

```
columns: [{
                field: 'email',
                title: 'Email',
                formatter: operateEmail,
                sortable: true,
            }]
```

and the operateEmail function is

```
function operateEmail(value, row, index) {
    if (index < 24){
        return ['<a class="memoryManager" href="/admin/users/view/'+ row['id']+'">'+value+'</a>'].join('');
    }
}
```

I am trying to show only 25 rows of data when I choose the page option on 50/100/All. but the result is the table show 25 rows with data, and the rest of the rows are blank. I have try to use the scroll function but doesnt seem work. how can i not showing the blank rows untill i scroll the windows?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have asked, have tried to simulate the scroll and fetch& append data. This might help you for the thought process. Thnx

```js
var glblIndex = 0;
window.onscroll = function (e) {  
// called when the window is scrolled.  
  $('#appendMe').append(getDummyData(++glblIndex));
}

function getDummyData(nextVal){
 if (nextVal< 100)
  return "<div class='row'><div class='col-md-4'>"+nextVal+++"</div></div>"
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="appendMe">
dummy till page fill
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
dummy till page fill
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
dummy till page fill
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
dummy till page fill
<br/><br/><br/>
dummy till page fill
<br/><br/><br/>
dummy till page fill
<br/><br/><br/>
dummy till page fill
<br/><br/><br/>
dummy till page fill
</div>
```

Comment: but how can I not showing/loading more than 100 rows when I click the 'All' option one the pageList.

Comment: You can control your data inside the logic from where you are fetching. I have updated the answer to only return 99 records.

Comment: Pass the off sets(start/end) to the function and return next 100 records per scroll and keep updating the offsets .You can use this way.

Comment: It doesn't work because when I including the option 'All' in the bootstrap-table, all the records will be shown in the table. I checked [link] (https://bootstrap-table-docs3.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#methods)but there is no table option to do some kind of lazy loading stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jquery? I have 800 data and it is fast, solved it for you on my [codepen](https://codepen.io/agandurmisevic/pen/eYVrdmR).

```js
$( "#update" ).click(function() {
  for(let i = 1; i <= 800; i++) {
    $('#table tr:last').after("<tr><td>Some data here</td><td>Some data " + i + " here</td><td>" + "<img src='https://i.pravatar.cc/300?u=random' width: '40' height='40'></td></tr>");
  }
});
```

```css
#table img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.8.1/bootstrap-table.css">
<div class="container mx-5 px-5">
  <div style="margin : 100px;">
            <button class="btn-primary btn" id="update">ALL Table</button>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-sm table-dark table-bordered table-striped table-responsive align-middle" id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
                    <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
                    <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Some data here</td>
              <td>Some data here</td>
              <td><img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?u=random" width: '40' height='40'>
                
              </td>
                
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```